# Showing GTK debug log messages

Tags: c, logging, gtk

I'm sort of new to GTK+, and I'm starting my first project (a window manager). My question is this: I write a program that has a lot of debug messages, written as:

```
g_debug("foo");
...
g_debug("bar");
```

I'm just wondering how to show them, because they don't show while running the application. I've tried to run the application like this:

```
./foobar --gtk-debug=all --gdk-debug=all
```

But the debug messages still don't show. I'm sure I'm missing something, but I can't seem to find the way (googled a lot before asking this, trust me).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try setting the [G_MESSAGES_DEBUG](https://developer-old.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-running.html#G_MESSAGES_DEBUG) environment variable to 'all'

```
G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all ./foobar
```